# What language uses `and` and `or` keywords to mean "do this thing without affecting the result"?

Tags: syntax, boolean-logic, flow-control, unknown-language

I remember encountering a language that has `&&` and `||` for boolean logic, but also `and` and `or` keywords that have a special purpose.

Something like `a = b and print "correct"` would set `a` equal to `b`, and *then if `b` was true* it would print "correct" without attempting to set `a` equal to the result of `print`. Kinda like:

```
a = b
if (b) print "correct"
```

Likewise, `or` meant "if false do this thing without affecting the result", thus...

`a = b or print_fail_message()`

...was effectively identical to...

```
a = b
if (!b) print_fail_message()
```

The bit after the `and` or `or` did not change the value of the preceding code. I can't remember what language it was.

Comment: If `print` and `print_fail_message` are both Boolean functions, there's nothing special going on - it's similar to Pascal, for example, except that assignment would be `:=` and that the `"correct"` argument would require parenthesis.

Comment: Really now? Suppose `a` and `b` are integers. Or strings. Or class instances. Or suppose the functions didn't return booleans, but rather `void`. That would be an invalid cast error or similar in most languages. But not this language. Because this language has special meanings for `and` and `or`.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess an arbitrary language can do anything that it wants.